# Use of plt.plot vs plt.scatter with two variables (x and f(x,y))

Tags: numpy

I am new in Python and stack overflow so please bear with me.
I was trying to plot using plt.plot and plt.scatter. The former works perfectly alright while the latter not. Down below is the relevant part of code:

```
enter code here
def vis_cal(u, a):
     return np.exp(2*np.pi*1j*u*np.cos(a))

u = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
u = u.reshape((4,1))

a = a([[-np.pi, -np.pi/6]]) 

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.xlabel("Baseline") 
plt.ylabel("Vij (Visibility)")

plt.scatter(u, vis_cal(u, a), 'o', color='blue', label="Vij_ind")

plt.legend(loc="lower left")

plt.show()
```

This returns an error: ValueError: x and y must be the same size

My questions here are

1. Why the different array size doesn't matter to plt.plot but it does matter to plt.scatter?
2. Does this mean that if I want to use plt.scatter I always need to make sure that they arrays must have the same size otherwise I need to use plt.plot?

Thank you very much

Comment: The 'x' argument in your plot/scatter call is a 4x1 array, the 'y' argument is a 4x2 array. the function 'plot' treats the array as two functions sampled at the same places along the x axis that you want to plot. While the function 'scatter' is supposed to plot points in the two-dimensional space so it requires a set of point coordinates. that means that each x coordinate, there should be a y coordinate

Comment: Thank you very much Yan, it is very clear now